# AND operator behavior with/without brackets

Tags: php

```
$a = true and false; //true
$b = true && false; //false
$c = (true and false); //false
$d = (true && false); //false
```

Why gives case 'a'  true?

I thought that and and && has the same precedence but [they don't](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: Assignment operator `=` has higher precedence than `and`. Check [`Operator Precedence`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, this is expected bahvior

```
// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

The constant true is assigned to $a and then false is ignored. It's all about operator precedences